# C Compiler thinks char type is int type - clang compiler

Tags: c, compiler-errors, type-conversion, cs50

So I am going through one of those edX courses in computer science (not for credit, just to have lectures to help self-learning) and the advanced problem set has to do with decrypting passwords.  To get a better understanding of the function crypt() used to make the encryptions, I made the following code to figure out what was being used for the "salts" string (the man crypt() command in the terminal said: ("salt is a two-character string chosen from the set [a-zA-Z0-9./].  This string is used to perturb the algorithm in one of 4096 different ways."))  Please tell me if you can see why I am getting this error.

Below is the code I used.  I am getting this error when attempting to compile:

```
test.c:37:33: error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to
parameter of type 'char *'; take the address with & [-Werror,-Wint-conversion]
char *salt = strcat(whatever1,whatever2);
```

Code:

```
    #define _XOPEN_SOURCE //this is needed for the unistd and crypt stuff
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <unistd.h> //this lets me do the crypt() fcn
    #include <cs50.h> //just lets me use string as a type among w/some input fcns and       is made by the course
    #include <string.h>
    #include <ctype.h> //this lets me use toascii()

    char *word = "caesar";
    char *password;

    char toASCII_New(int i) //attempt to turn input to HEX then corresponding ASCII character
    {
        for(int num = i; num<= 172; num++)
        {
            for(int hex_num = 0x41; hex_num <= 0x7a; hex_num++)
            {
                if(num == hex_num)
                {
                    char letter = (char) toascii(hex_num); //should convert hex to ascii here
                    return letter;
                }
            }
        }
        char backup = 'a';
        return backup;
    }


    string checker(int first, int second) //Checks the inputs to see if the can be the correct SALTS input to crypt
    {
        for (int i = first; i<=first+25; i++)
        {
            for(int j = second; j<=second+25; j++)
            {
                char whatever1 = (char) toASCII_New(i);
                char whatever2 = (char) toASCII_New(j);
                char *salt = strcat(whatever1,whatever2);
                password = crypt(word,salt);
                int compare = strcmp(password,"50zPJlUFIYY0o"); // this is what i'm really checking
                if (compare == 0)
                    return salt;

            }
        }
    return "no";
    }


    int main(void)
    {
        string AA = checker(65,65);
        string Aa = checker(65,97);
        string aA = checker(97,65);
        string aa = checker(97,97);

        printf("AA: %s\nAa: %s\naA: %s\naa: %s\n",AA,Aa,aA,aa);
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to acheive with `toASCII_New` ? I don't think you should use `toascii` in the first place. And also, why would you cast a `char` to a `char` (when calling `toASCII_New`) ? There is a lot more details like that but they would help reading and understanding your code.

Comment: What is `string` in C?

Comment: @barakmanos In the code, line 4.

Comment: @Nelxiost: yeah I saw that, but note the "is made by the course" comment next to it. Are we supposed to guess how the `string` structure is implemented there???

Comment: @barakmanos I've seen that header before. its `char*` (yeah, academia still doesn't get what a bad idea that is).

Comment: @barakmanos Well, you are right in that way : Daniel Schapira doesn't show the whole code. But it is probably not very important here because it is only used in `main` (and as return of `checker`). If I had to guess, I would say `typedef char* string`.

Comment: The title of this question is utter nonsense that has nothing to do with the error message.

Comment: @barakmanos It's not relevant ... did you even look at the line that got the error message?

Comment: The `toASCII_New()` function shows a lack of understanding of what a `char`, an `int` and a "hex value" are.  The entire body of the function can be replaced with `if (('A' <= i) && (i <= 'z')) return i; return 'a';`  The reason for the nested loops escapes me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

strcat is for concatenating *strings* not 2 separate chars. "whatever1" will hold the joined string together. Why using -dangerous- strcat operations when all you have to do is to have a 2-byte string ? Just use something like:

```
char salt[3];
salt[0]=toASCII_New(i); /* why the casting to char ? you already returned a char... */
salt[1]=toASCII_New(j);
salt[2]='\0'; /* to terminate the string properly */
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here are some general advices, as the entire code needs to be refactored:**

---

Function `toASCII_New` should be rewritten as follows:

```
char toASCII_New(int c)
{
    if (('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') || ('a' <= c && c <= 'z'))
        return (char)toascii(c);
    return 'a';
}
```

---

Function `checker` should be rewritten as follows:

```
int checker(int first, int second, char salt[3])
{
    for (int i=first; i<=first+25; i++)
    {
        for (int j=second; j<=second+25; j++)
        {
            salt[0] = toASCII_New(i);
            salt[1] = toASCII_New(j);
            password = crypt(word,salt);
            if (strcmp(password,"50zPJlUFIYY0o") == 0)
                return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

Function `main` should be rewritten as follows:

```
int main()
{
    char salt_AA[3] = {0};
    char salt_Aa[3] = {0};
    char salt_aA[3] = {0};
    char salt_aa[3] = {0};
    int  salt_AA_OK = checker('A','A');
    int  salt_Aa_OK = checker('A','a');
    int  salt_aA_OK = checker('a','A');
    int  salt_aa_OK = checker('a','a');
    printf("AA: %s\n",salt_AA_OK? salt_AA:"failed");
    printf("Aa: %s\n",salt_Aa_OK? salt_Aa:"failed");
    printf("aA: %s\n",salt_aA_OK? salt_aA:"failed");
    printf("aa: %s\n",salt_aa_OK? salt_aa:"failed");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `crypt()` function is the old Unix API: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html

Comment: @MichaelBurr: So from the description of `crypt_r` (the reentrant version of `crypt`), I take it that `crypy` uses a `static` string in order to return the password, right?

Comment: Yes. "The return value points to static data whose content is overwritten by each call"

Comment: @MichaelBurr: OK, so I removed my comment on the dynamic allocation of the password then. Thank you for pointing that out :)